# What Happen To Uploaded files in Windows Azure

Tags: windows

I only started to use Windows Azure yesterday so I think this question is a Newbie question.
Lets say I use the deployed application that I have for a month, during this period I upload a lots of images to server (I upload them to where my projects is), after one month I decide to release the new code, what will happen to my currently uploaded images that are in my project ?

Do they get deleted as well ? If the answer is yes then how can I guaranty that they don't get deleted every time I deploy new code ?

I appreciate your answer.

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: It is a programming question because without servers there would be no website to see.

Answer (score 3):

When you upload new images, you don't want to upload them to your vm instances, as each time those are restarted (due to your code updates, OS updates, hardware failures, etc.), they revert to how they originally were.

You want to upload images to either Windows Azure blob storage or SQL Azure, both of which are outside of your vm instances and are considered *durable storage* (replicated at least 3 times within the data center).

You can look at the examples in the [Windows Azure Platform Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=413e88f8-5966-4a83-b309-53b7b77edf78) for working with SQL Azure and blob storage.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I will try to learn about Azure blob, it seems like the way forward for me.